# Return-To-Libc Function Address Probing

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, libc

I'm trying to implement a return-to-libc buffer overflow attack by finding the address of `system()` with gdb and returning to said address with `/bin/sh` passed as an argument to `system()` on the stack. The only problem is, I can't find the address in memory where `system()` lives, as running `print system` in gdb returns "No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command.", which isn't especially helpful, as loading libc.so into gdb doesn't do me any good. Is there a way I can find the addresses of functions in libc which I have not included via headers?

For reference, the code I'm testing this with is below, DEP is enabled, and ASLR is disabled.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(char *arg) {
    char buf[100];
    strcpy(buf, arg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    foo(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this is merely an academic question and not something you're trying to do evil with, try adding `printf("system() is at %p\n", system);` to your program.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only seems to work when stdlib is included, which I am unable to do in this case. And yes, just to be clear, this is for academic purposes :)

Comment: Do you mean you're unable to `#include <stdlib.h>` for some reason? Inclusion of a header is not necessary to make the function available (it's just the best practice method of doing that). You could also provide the prototype manually, by adding `int system(const char *);` in this case. Neither will modify what the compiler produces for the linked executable.

Comment: I should say, I'm trying to do this without including stdlib. Regardless, I couldn't print the address of `system` without stdlib included (or if system was forward-declared), unless I was doing something wrong.